# Can I put Windows Server 2012 onto VirtualBox on Windows XP?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

If I have a PC running Windows XP SP3 32 bit on which VirtualBox is installed, could I install Windows Server 2012 in VirtualBox as it requires 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

From [the virtualbox website](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html):

VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:

1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support
2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.

So for virtual box you need a 64 bit CPU (just about every x86 CPU from the last decade is 64 bits) and one with virtualization support (That is rarer. Usually that means a core i7 or an AMD CPU)

Alternatively you could try qemu and have it **emulate** 64 bits, but it would be **extremely slow**.

The other way around ( Server 2012 as OS and XP in a VM ) would work fine.